# Forcing code-first to always initialize a non-existent database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first

Sometimes, I'll delete my development database and run my EF code-first application.  I'll get the error:

> Cannot open database "AssessmentSystem" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'AssessmentAdmin'.

I think this is because the `DbContext` only runs the DB initialization logic "once per AppDomain when the context is used for the first time", as [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) says.  This means I need to recycle the IIS application pool to get EF to recreate my database if I drop it.

Is there any way I can get the DB initialization code to run *every time* I try to access the database?  So, it will always check to see whether the DB exists and if not, create it instead of trying to open it, even if it's using the same AppDomain that previously accessed the database that I have now dropped?

Note that I would like this initializtion check to be done on *every query*, so even having it done in `Application_Start` isn't often enough; ideally, I'd like to be able to load some DB data, delete the DB, then load some DB data and it would recreate the DB without my even having to restart the application (basically I would just have to reload the web page that loads some DB data).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Initializer** is executed when you need to access the database so if you want to create database on app start use anything of the following:

```
    context.Database.Initialize(true); //If set to true the initializer is run even if it has already been run.       
    context.Database.Create()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.103).aspx

**CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**
An implementation of IDatabaseInitializer that will recreate and optionally re-seed the database with data only if the database does not exist. To seed the database, create a derived class and override the Seed method.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.103).aspx

**DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges**
An implementation of IDatabaseInitializerthat will delete, recreate, and optionally re-seed the database with data only if the model has changed since the database was created. This is achieved by writing a hash of the store model to the database when it is created and then comparing that hash with one generated from the current model. To seed the database, create a derived class and override the Seed method.

> The initialization strategy can optionally check for database
>   existence, create a new database, and seed the database with data. The
>   default strategy is an instance of
>   CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());

> Note that this assumes you have permission to even drop your database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604(v=vs.103).aspx

**DropCreateDatabaseAlways**

An implementation of IDatabaseInitializer that will always recreate and optionally re-seed the database with data the first time that a context is used in the application domain. To seed the database, create a derived class and override the Seed method.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.103).aspx

I recommend that you look at **Migrations** if you want to track, revert the changes you made to your DB to the previous state http://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/data/jj591621 .

**UPDATE**

```
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

> If the parameter force is set to true, then the initializer is run
>   regardless of whether or not it has been run before. This can be
>   useful if a database is deleted while an app is running and needs to
>   be reinitialized.

For MVC application add a section to the `Application_Start()` method in the **Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start() {

     Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>()); 

     // Forces initialization of database on model changes.
     using (var context= new MyContext()) {
          context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
     }    
}
```

Also you can use a custom initializer :

```
public class MyDbInit : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
{

}
```

and then use

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInit());
```

**UPDATE 2**

Make a new empty MVC4 application called **DeleteDBOnEveryRequest**.
Put the following in the Global.asax Application_start

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            Database.SetInitializer<BlogContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());    

            using (var context = new BlogContext())
            {
                context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
            }    
        }
```

Make a new controller called **DatabaseController** with two actions.

In the **Access** action you delete the DB and redirect to **Recreated** action from where you create a DB as it was previousy deleted.

```
namespace DeleteDBOnEveryRequest.Controllers
{
    public class DatabaseController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Access()
        {
            using (var context = new BlogContext())
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
            } 
            return RedirectToAction("Recreated");
        }

        public ActionResult Recreated()
        {
            using (var context = new BlogContext())
            {
                context.Database.Initialize(force: true);                
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No; `Initializer` is only run once per AppDomain when the context is used for the first time.  I'm looking to initialize the database if it doesn't exist *any time I try to access it, even if that context has been used to access the database before*.

Comment: So you want to recreate DB if it doesn't exist on every query you make?

Comment: Yes. (stackoverflow requires this extra text or i can't post the comment)

Comment: That's pretty good and is 99% there, but it does still only apply on application start.  While that's usually good enough, it would be nice to have a solution where I load a page that accesses the DB, delete the DB, then reload that page and the DB is recreated.  As it is, I need to make some change to the app code to trigger an application start before this kicks in (which I admit is still much better than before).

Comment: I'm currently not at my computer, so give me an hour or so to provide you with that solution.

Comment: Did you ever come up with that solution?  :-)

Comment: Sorry i wasn't able to respond sooner. Please check the updated answer and mark as accepted if appropriate.