# Update database from CodeFirst in EF6 without wiping out data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I want to use Code First Technique of EF6 but when i made changes to table, it drops the database and recreates it, wiping out all data.
Is there any way to stop this from happening?

My Code :

```
Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDb>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EmployeeDb>());
```

Comment: You also gave the answer. Your code says that, it drops and creates database if you change your model.

Comment: i wish to know if it there is an alternative to this where i can use code first but on updating table don't have to recreate database.

Comment: you can use Code First Migrations
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

These are the strategies for database initilization in code first approach:

1. **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists:** This is default initializer. As the name suggests, it will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception.
2. **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges:** This initializer drops an existing database and creates a new database, if your model classes (entity classes) have been changed. So you don't have to worry about maintaining your database schema, when your model classes change.
3. **DropCreateDatabaseAlways:** As the name suggests, this initializer drops an existing database every time you run the application, irrespective of whether your model classes have changed or not. This will be useful, when you want fresh database, every time you run the application, like while you are developing the application.
4. **Custom DB Initializer:** You can also create your own custom initializer, if any of the above doesn't satisfy your requirements or you want to do some other process that initializes the database using the above initializer.

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm), it can give you general idea and how to use one of these approaches.

Due to your comments `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` helps you. With this approach when you add or remove your model classes, your `db` will be updated and your data will be stable.

[Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) you can find examples both `Context` constructor and `config` file

[Another topic about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546241/entityframework-6-0-createdatabaseifnotexists-code-first-to-create-database) on stackoverflow.