# Forcing EF 6 to create tables with model first

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

Currently I have a nice model, and I can generate a database based on that, but from what I can tell, the tables are never created (leading to all  sorts of fun runtime errors).

My understanding is that there are three options for code first that would force EF to create the tables for me:

- DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

How can I use these if I am doing things model first?

Additionally, is this an expected error, or when I selected generate database from model the first time is this supposed to happen automatically?

**Edit:** I tried calling

```
            context.Database.Initialize(true);
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

and nothing changes.

Comment: look at this [force initialize database][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724320/forcing-code-first-to-always-initialize-a-non-existent-database

Comment: @ilayzeidman where is the `.SetInitializer()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also this is good toturial
[tutorial](http://codefirst.codeplex.com/)

but if you made the model good the first time you access the dbContext the db should be created by the db strategy which you can set: Database.SetInitializer()
[set initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

in short after you create your model you need to create class that inherit from DbContext:

```
 public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext() : base("CompanyDatabase") { }

    public DbSet<Collaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

and then when you access this context the tables should be generated.
you can also seed the database with data you should inherit from the strategy you want to implement look at this link [seeding database](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: If the model is only good now (it was not before) how can I update it to the tables? Generate database from model does not seem to do the trick. Also, I cannot find that method. Do I set it on the context?

Comment: Yes it should do the trick I did it lot of time you create your own class that inherited from DbContext?

Comment: I have created none of my own classes. I need to do that?

Comment: No it is static method in  System.Data.Entity

Comment: I want to understand you have just the model classes?

Comment: public class YourContext: DbContext
    {
        
 
        public DbSet<YourEntity> nameOfEntity{ get; set; }
        
    }   you have such class?

Comment: Ok, so I have set the model strategy, and now it is telling me that I cannot the database (master) as it is a sytem database. How can I get EF to create a new database (not master, model, tempdb or msdb) so that I will not get this error?

Comment: I know this error you can change the connection string in the app config to create to you sql compact database or other db like sql express

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44638/discussion-between-soandos-and-ilay-zeidman)