# Create Database If Not Exist Without Restarting Application

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am creating dynamic connection strings in my project. They're created on the fly with the information provided specifically for every user. When the application first fires off, if a database doesn't exist (first time user logs on), a new database is created without problems with this initializer:

```
public DataContext() : base()
{
    // ProxyCreation and LazyLoading doesn't affect the situation so
    // comments may be removed
    //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    //this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    string conStr = GetDb();
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = conStr;
}
```

The problem is, with this method, I have to restart the application pool on the server and the new user should be the first accessor to the application.

I need the same thing without a requirement of restarting the app. Is that possible?

(This is a SPA using AngularJS on MVC views and WebApi as data provider - May be relevant somehow, so thought I should mention)

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724320/forcing-code-first-to-always-initialize-a-non-existent-database), but this creates an error for EF and the application doesn't start at all...

Comment: What error occurs when you call `context.Database.Initialize(true);`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a little bit different approach to connect directly (and create) the right database.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }
}
```

Here you create the DbContext already with the right connection.

Take also care because you need to specify to migrations that the right connection should be used (not the Web.Config connection but the connection that raised the database creation).
See the second overload here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh829099(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.