# My database is not getting automatically created by Entity Framework 6 code-first approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I am trying to create a database using code first approach for an online exam system. I have already created my data models, my context class, added my `setInitializer` method in the `Global.asax` file, added my connection string.

But still the database isn't getting created. Would really use some help.

My connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExamDbContext" 
         connectionString="server=LAPTOP-JJKI9JN7; Initial Catalog=OnlineExamSystem; Integrated Security=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    </add> 
</connectionStrings>
```

`LAPTOP-JJKI9JN7` is my SSMS server name

**Student** table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Online_Exam_System.Models
{
    public class TBL_STUDENT
    {
        public int S_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Student")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string S_NAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string S_PASSWORD { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Marks")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public Nullable<int> S_MARKS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Question** table :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Online_Exam_System.Models
{
    public class TBL_QUESTIONS
    {
        public int QUESTION_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Question")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string QUESTION_TEXT { get; set; }


        public string OPTION { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OPTION A")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string OPTIONA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OPTION B")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string OPTIONB { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OPTION C")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string OPTIONC { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OPTION D")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string OPTIOND { get; set; }

        public string CORRECT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Admin** table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Online_Exam_System.Models
{
    public class TBL_ADMIN
    {
        public int AD_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string AD_NAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string AD_PASSWORD { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My context class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using Online_Exam_System.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Online_Exam_System.Data_Access_Layer
{
    public class ExamDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ExamDbContext() : base("ExamDbContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TBL_ADMIN> TBL_ADMIN { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TBL_QUESTIONS> TBL_QUESTIONS { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TBL_EXAM> TBL_SETEXAM { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TBL_STUDENT> TBL_STUDENT { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

My Initializer method (it's inside the `Model` folder)

```
using Online_Exam_System.Data_Access_Layer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Online_Exam_System.Models
{
    public class ExamInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ExamDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ExamDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

`Global.asax` file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Optimization;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    namespace Online_Exam_System
    {
            public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
            {
                protected void Application_Start()
                {
                    Database.SetInitializer(new 
                    NullDatabaseInitializer<ExamDbContext>());
                    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

                    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters
                    (GlobalFilters.Filters);
                    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your initializer, force it to run by either accessing the context somewhere or forcing it:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<ExamDbContext>());
// Forces initialization of database on model changes.
using (var context= new ExamDbContext ()) {
   context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

[Forcing code-first to always initialize a non-existent database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724320/forcing-code-first-to-always-initialize-a-non-existent-database)

Comment: The error is: An object reference is required for non-static field , method or property 'Database.Initialize(bool)'

Comment: Yeah, you may need to run it within your context. See edit.

Comment: Ok the error got resolved , but again it's not creating the database. Can u check my connectionString and make sure there's no problems with that.And if so, can u tell me an alternative to resolve this issue.

Comment: OK, I see an issue. You are setting your initializer to null instead of using the one your created. Try: `Database.SetInitializer(new  ExamInitializer <ExamDbContext>());`

Comment: Thank You so much Steve. That actually resolved my problem. I needed to use the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists() instead of NullDatabaseInitializer(). This created the database . Really was a big help. Had been stuck on it for days. Appreciate.

Comment: Right, you probably want the one you created in case you add Seed code later.